# Surround text with quotes in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

**Is there a possibilty to easily surround a certain text element in my Android Studio project with quotes?**

More specifically without manually typing one quote before and another quote after the text?

For example: `some text` should become `"some text"` with minimal effort?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Android Studio (as well as IntelliJ) provides the functionality of certain Smart Keys, which can be found under

> Settings > Editor > General > Smart Keys > Surround selection on typing quote or brace

[image: android studio smart keys]

If enabled and a certain text is highlighted and a quote is typed the previously highlighted text gets surroundes with quotes (single or double quotes work both, as well as any kind of brackets).